# ArcGIS Online will not map lat longs!

Tags: arcgis-online, latitude-longitude, feature-layer

I'm trying to "add new" hosted feature layer from either a .csv or .xls in ArcGIS Online. But, I cannot for the life of me get it to plot the XY data! I'm at a loss because I'm used to the old Desktop software from years ago, and trying to do this with only access to ArcGIS Online.

It will load the data (~2700 items), but does nothing spatially to plot it. I've tried reformatting, but when uploading it only allows to pick one field (not two columns for x,y), and I think the issue may be that the column I created to combine lat/long into one XX.XX, -YY.YY is coming through as a "string".

How do I get this formatting correctly for ArcGIS Online to recognize and plot the lat/long data I have in the table!?

Comment: Add a screen shot of the excel column? How does it looks? Seems something is wrong with how they are formatted when you say "combined".

Answer (score 0):

Map it like my image below, your Latitude should be y and your Longitude should be x assuming these are WGS 1984 coordinates.

[image]